# Counting Duplicate word in Java String. Odd Terminal display

Tags: java, algorithm

I am learning Java coding for automation Interviews.  The question is super simple.

***Write how many times is a word displayed in a string.***

I wrote out code perfectly (or so I thought) but I got an odd output in my terminal.

code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class TimesAWordAppearsInString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        //step 1. Declare sentence to be used in this class 
        String str ="I am learning learning java java programming";

        //step 2.Create HashMap here! To count the amount times a word appears in the sentence 
        Map<String,Integer> map=new HashMap<String,Integer>();

        //step 2a Get the HashMap to Count from starting place 
        Integer count = 1;

        //step3.Split the string to include the spaces by converting it into an ARRAY (arr)
        String[] arr=str.split(" ");

        //step 4. Using the for...IF....else loop count the number of words in this string
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length;i++){

            //4a. How many times the word occurs 

               //4a.1 starting the process of counting the number times a word
                 //appear in the array and its duplicates.  If there is a duplicate words use ELSE!
              if(!map.containsKey(arr[i])){
                  map.put(arr[i], count);

              }else{
                  map.put(arr[i], map.get(arr[i])+1); //get instance of the duplicate and increase by 1 for occurrence
              }
              //5.printout of string output
              //5.1. go into the String and printout the word
               for(String x:map.keySet()){
                   System.out.println("The count for word :"+x+"="+map.get(x));
               }




        }

    }

}
```

The out put is of odd and not what I expected.

I was expecting :

> The count of word Java = 3 
>   The count of word I = 1 
>   The count learning = 2

etc etc.  What is got is what was displayed below.  Once again.  What did I do wrong?

Output.

```
The count for word :I=1
The count for word :I=1
The count for word :am=1
The count for word :I=1
The count for word :learning=1
The count for word :am=1
The count for word :I=1
The count for word :learning=2
The count for word :am=1
The count for word :java=1
The count for word :I=1
The count for word :learning=2
The count for word :am=1
The count for word :java=2
The count for word :I=1
The count for word :learning=2
The count for word :am=1
The count for word :java=2
The count for word :I=1
The count for word :learning=2
The count for word :am=1
The count for word :programming=1
```

Comment: You should also give meaningful name to your variables `words`instead of `arr`, `word`instead of `x`...

Comment: Totally agree.  I will do that next time.

Answer (score 1):

You have put your 2nd for loop inside the first one. update as follow:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class TimesAWordAppearsInString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        //step 1. Declare sentence to be used in this class 
        String str ="I am learning learning java java programming";

        //step 2.Create HashMap here! To count the amount times a word appears in the sentence 
        Map<String,Integer> map=new HashMap<String,Integer>();

        //step 2a Get the HashMap to Count from starting place 
        Integer count = 1;

        //step3.Split the string to include the spaces by converting it into an ARRAY (arr)
        String[] arr=str.split(" ");

        //step 4. Using the for...IF....else loop count the number of words in this string
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length;i++){

            //4a. How many times the word occurs 

               //4a.1 starting the process of counting the number times a word
                 //appear in the array and its duplicates.  If there is a duplicate words use ELSE!
              if(!map.containsKey(arr[i])){
                  map.put(arr[i], count);

              }else{
                  map.put(arr[i], map.get(arr[i])+1); //get instance of the duplicate and increase by 1 for occurrence
              }

        }

          //5.printout of string output
          //5.1. go into the String and printout the word
           for(String x:map.keySet()){
               System.out.println("The count for word :"+x+"="+map.get(x));
           }

    }

}
```

Comment: Just as a quick aside too, he probably wants `System.out.print` instead of `println` because he is expecting it all on a single line, along with a `" "` to separate each print.

Comment: @CZ54 Can you show me exactly where I did it?  Was around 4 or the print out at 5?   That way I won't make the same mistake again

Comment: @Nexevis  thanks man.  I had been working on this for over an hour.  Not a natural coder so progress is super slow

Comment: @fypnlpThe Step5 should not be inside the brackets of step 4 otherwise you will run it for every word of your "arr"

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're printing out the output of your hashmap (with the loop shown below) with every iteration of your bigger for-loop to add counts to the map.

```
for(String x:map.keySet()){
     System.out.println("The count for word :"+x+"="+map.get(x));
}
```

Try moving it outside of your for-loop, and you'll see the results you want.